# How to wire Awesomium WebControl events with Prism MVVM

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, awesomium

I inherited a WPF MVVM project which uses Prism MVVM.  I want to use the Awesomium WebControl on a view.  I have defined the WebControl in the xaml as below:

```
<awe:WebControl Name="taskBrowser" Source="http://localhost:59298/Tasks" Height="680" Width="680">
```

This works fine, but I also need to be able to pass data from Javascript events in the web page to the WPF app.  I have this working when I do it in the code-behind, but since we're using MVVM, I want to do things the "right" way and somehow not do it in the code behind, but in the ViewModel.  So problem 1 is: I need to wire up a DocumentReady event in the ViewModel as shown below.

Problem 2 is:  I would need some reference to the taskBrowser in the ViewModel to be able to do the  "taskBrowser.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject" command as seen below to wire up the web page js to the WPF method.  But is having a reference to the taskBrowser object in the ViewModel un-MVVM?  How could I pass this reference?  Anyway, can anyone tell me how to approach these two problems?

```cs
public MyCodeBehindConstructor()
{
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        taskBrowser.DocumentReady += TaskBrowserOnDocumentReady;
    }
}

private void TaskBrowserOnDocumentReady(object sender, UrlEventArgs urlEventArgs)
{
    taskBrowser.DocumentReady -= TaskBrowserOnDocumentReady;
    JSObject jsobject = taskBrowser.CreateGlobalJavascriptObject("jsobject");
    jsobject.Bind("callNETNoReturn", false, JSHandler);
}

private void JSHandler(object sender, JavascriptMethodEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.MustReturnValue)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got method call with return request");
        args.Result = "Returning " + args.Arguments[0];
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Got method call with no return request");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just released a new framework that can make all the plumbing between a C# ViewModel and awesomium. 
Basically, you need one call to link a viewmodel to a IWebView and then the framework will create javascripts objects that wil reflect the C# view model.
It is based on knouckout.js so it is full MVVM.
ICommand are also mapped to javascript method that you can bind using knouckout mark-up. Collection and property changed are tracked via INotityPropertyChanged and INotityCollectionChanged.
You can find the whole project with examples on github: https://github.com/David-Desmaisons/MVVM-for-awesomium
Ex: view model:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected void Set<T>(ref T ipnv, T value, string ipn)
        {
            if (object.Equals(ipnv, value))
                return;
            ipnv = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(ipn);
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string pn)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pn));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

   public class Person: ViewModelBase
    {
        public Person()
        {
            Skills = new ObservableCollection<Skill>();
            RemoveSkill = new RelayCommand<Skill>(s=> this.Skills.Remove(s));
        }

        private string _LastName;
        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _LastName; }
            set { Set(ref _LastName, value, "LastName"); }
        }

        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { Set(ref _Name, value, "Name"); }
        }

        public IList<Skill> Skills { get; private set; }

        public ICommand RemoveSkill { get; private set; }
    }
```

View (HTML+ knockout mark-up):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="js/knockout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/Ko_Extension.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Name, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" placeholder="First name" >
        <ul data-bind="foreach: Skills">
            <li><span data-bind="text:Type"></span>:<span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
            <button data-bind="click: function (){$root.RemoveSkill($data)}">Remove skill</button></li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <h2><span data-bind="text: Name"></span></h2>
            <h2><span data-bind="text: LastName"></span></h2>
        </div>

        <button data-bind="click: ChangeSkill">Click me</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Binding:

```
IWebView mywebview = ...; //retrieve awesomium view wich loaded the HTML view
var datacontext = new Person();
AwesomeBinding.Bind(mywebview, datacontext, JavascriptBindingMode.TwoWay);
```